# Spring Webflow 2 - basic conditional flow without beans

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I'm new to SWF (2.3.1), and am playing around to see if I can get something basic working. When I say 'basic', I really do mean basic. At this stage if I can possibly avoid it, I want to avoid writing any java. I just want to get a quick and dirty flow working, ideally all in the flow config.

I have managed to get a very basic linear flow working, going from view-state (screen?) A to B to C (AboutYou to AboutYourCar to YourQuote)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <view-state id="AboutYou" view="/WEB-INF/views/jsp/motor/AboutYou.jsp">
        <transition on="Next" to="AboutYourCar" />
    </view-state>


    <view-state id="AboutYourCar" view="/WEB-INF/views/jsp/motor/AboutYourCar.jsp">
        <transition on="Back" to="AboutYou" />
        <transition on="Next" to="YourQuote" />
    </view-state>                               

    <view-state id="Modifications" view="/WEB-INF/views/js/motor/Modifications.jsp">
        <transition on="Back" to="AboutYourCar" />  
    </view-state>

    <view-state id="YourQuote" view="/WEB-INF/views/jsp/motor/YourQuote.jsp">
        <transition on="Back" to="AboutYou" />
    </view-state>                               
</flow>
```

In the AboutYourCar view, I have an input field asking if the car has been modified:

```
Is your car modified?
<input type="radio" name="modified" value="No">
<input type="radio" name="modified" value="Yes">
```

What I would like to do is go to the Modifications view-state if the request parameter 'modified' is Yes; but I cant work out how to do this.

I think I would be able to get it working with an action-state, but (as I understand it) you need to provide an action bean which would perform some logic.

I also think I might be able to use a decision-state, but again, not really sure how I would write it.

Or maybe my whole approach is wrong, and that Modifications is not a view-state, but actually should be a sub-view??

Any help anyone could offer would be very much appreciated,

Thanks, Nathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
<decision-state id="checkSelection">
    <if test="requestParameters.modified == 'Yes'" then="Modifications" else="YourQuote"/>
</decision-state>
```

See [Spring EL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) for what you can do with the Expression Language available within the flow configuration file (with or without your own Java objects) and [EL Variables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.7.RELEASE/reference/html/el.html#el-variables) for the implicit variables available to Spring WebFlow.